# It is possible to create .NetCore and Angular2 Hybrid Application

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core, razor-pages

[image]

I am creating an application using .net core and angular2,
Can I load angular component in Razor view Pages?

Comment: Might not be exactly what you have in mind, but have you looked into [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) already?

Comment: You can create custom [web components](https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction) and you can reference them in your Razor page. See this [guide](https://alligator.io/angular/using-custom-elements/) how it is done in Angular. If you are targeting old web browsers you will have a couple of issues to overcome.

Comment: @MartinKlinke Question details updated please check once.

Comment: I thick this link could helps you https://ievangelistblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/building-an-angular2-spa-with-asp-net-5-mvc-6-web-api-2-and-typescript-1-7-5/

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify, by Angular2 do you mean Angular, or the specifically version 2 of Angular?

Angular 2.x and beyond is just Angular now.  Angular 1.x is called AngularJS

If you mean just .NET Core and Angular, there is .NET Core template for exactly this.

Either use the Visual Studio IDE to create a new web project and select 'Angular' in the templates, or you may also use the [`dotnet new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore22) command to scaffold a new project with .NET Core / MVC Core / Angular 8.

`dotnet new angular`

## update

I would highly discourage your proposal for a simple web application.  Angular is a Single Page Application (SPA) framework. What you are depicting is using Angular in a possibly many page application. Angular also comes with it's own tooling and a different package management system.  It would be difficult to manage both without some form of separation.

AngularJS / KnockoutJS / etc. are libraries that you can 'drop in' to a Razor page and would be more suited for what you are showing for a simple web application.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about **Angular** 
I know about .net core with Angular Template. But in that template Angular is running separately.

I want to load angular in razor page (.cshtml) of .Net core and run it.

I have updated question details please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to serve the Angular application using a razor page. Therefore you have to put the transpiled and bundled application in the `wwwroot` folder and you have to reference in your `index.cshtml` the output of your Angular build. For example if you put the built Angular app in `wwwroot/dist` then your `index.cshtml` could look like following:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "";
}

<app>Loading...</app>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="~/dist/main.js"></script>
    ...
}
```